# How can I change the background image of a button from another Form in C#?

Tags: c#, button, properties, imagelist

I have a button that when clicked, changes its background image and opens another Form. I want that this background image changes again when I close the 2nd form (Cam) clicking on the X cross at the right corner. How can I do that? Should I use FormClosed() or FormClosing() events? Thank you.

```
private void CamBox1btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
        Camera Cam = new Camera();  

        if (bln)
        {
            CamBox1btn.Image = imageList1.Images[10];
            Cam.ShowDialog();             
        }

        else
        {
            CamBox1btn.Image = imageList1.Images[8];                
        }
        bln = !bln;
    }
```

Comment: I just solved the problem. I'll leave the solution here in case anyone is struggling with the same problem:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form 1:

```
 private void CamBox1btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Camera Cam = new Camera();          
        if (Cam_bln)
        {
            CamBox1btn.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Camera_button_ON;
            Cam.eventForm += new ShowFrm(backgroundcolor_change_CAM);
            Cam.ShowDialog();

        }

        else
        {
            CamBox1btn.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Camera_button_OFF;                
        }
        Cam_bln = !Cam_bln;
    }

    void backgroundcolor_change_CAM()
    {
        Cam_bln = false;
        CamBox1btn.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Camera_button_OFF;
    }
```

Form2:

```
public delegate void ShowFrm();
public partial class Camera : Form
{

    public event ShowFrm eventForm;
    private void Camera_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        eventForm?.Invoke();
    }
}
```